# NPE android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw

Tags: android, view

i found a crash in firebase. I have no idea about the problem. Only alternative thing, i guess, is about that i hold the convertView in adapter and update it after downloading item change(even the listview is detached). All info is below. Any idea appreciated.

main crashes device:

- Oppo CPH1609
- Oppo CPH1729
- Vivo 1601
- Vivo 1609

main crashes android version :

- android 6.0
- android 7.1.1
- android 7.0
- android 5.1

Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnPreDrawListener.onPreDraw()' on a null object reference
       at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw + 944(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals + 2809(ViewRootImpl.java:2809)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal + 1663(ViewRootImpl.java:1663)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run + 7546(ViewRootImpl.java:7546)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run + 916(Choreographer.java:916)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks + 718(Choreographer.java:718)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame + 650(Choreographer.java:650)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run + 902(Choreographer.java:902)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 836(Handler.java:836)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 103(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 232(Looper.java:232)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6802(ActivityThread.java:6802)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 1103(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 964(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

My download list adapter:

```
public class DownloadsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  ...

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
          .inflate(R.layout.cartoon_lister_download_item, null);

      MyDownloader.setStatusChangedListener(new DownloadTaskItemStatusChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(...) {
          doUpdateConvertView(...)  //the listener may be call after a long time, i know this is not good. Any better way?  
        }
      });
    }

    doUpdateConvertView(...)
    return convertView;
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution on this issue? i'am also facing this same issue.